# how to avoid a request timing out when uploading and resizing large amount of images in Coldfusion?

Tags: image, coldfusion, amazon-s3, timeout

I'm running `Coldfusion8` and have a cfc, that loops through a set of database records.

Each record contains two fields `image path` and `image file`. I'm constructing a path for every image, upload it to a temp folder, resize and then store it to `S3`.

Depending on the number of records, this may take quite some time and I have not been able to successfully finish the upload cycle with larger sets of images (eventually times out).

I'm already settings my timeout threshold to `5000`, but it still does not seem enough.

I can pick up where I left, because I'm keeping a media log to check against, before uploading to S3. This way I can finish the task, but I need to trigger this function 5x to upload 400 items.

**Question:**
Is there way to avoid a timeout without setting (in S3 case) `httptimeout` to some `50000000`? And would it make sense to run this in a `CFTHREAD` or will this be a problem if the user leaves the import page while the system is still uploading?

Thanks for some insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CFthread to perform the task, but make sure you LOCK THE SCOPE! otherwise you could end up running this memory intensive proccess several times over and kill the server, you only want this proccess running once at a time if its so intensive.

You have other options though, if this is not something that your application users will need to run and its a one-off proccess your doing, you could set a scheduled task with an exceedingly long timeout to run overnight, when the server is not very high use, This allows you to set the timeout independently to the application so the rest of the application is unaffected by global timeout changes.

Another option is, if this is something users will be doing semi-regularly then a thread which pushes a notification via email, log or other means (Ajax or Websockets) letting the user know they're task is complete. This has the upside that timeouts can be changed, calculated on the amount of data to be proccessed dynamically at thread generation. However, if your not careful you can overload your server with many threads proccessing large datasets (plus log file read-write locks will be harder to manage).

I would encourage you though, to take this away and see what solution works for you and post your final solution so others can see what the outcome is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. So I could temporarily just set the timeout to .... a large number, while figuring out a smoother way?

Comment: You could, but check your logs first, if you have other templates that are timing out then they should be looked at too to make sure that you won't have too many 'hung' pages floating around whilst you work. I'd reccomend looking at the Docs for cflock, and cfthread and start your research there.

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot. For now, I'm ok (deadline...). This is the only place I'm using `forever-timeout`. Everything else is regular.